# Giving full access to eth1 to docker container

Tags: networking, docker

Can I run `docker` container that will have access to `eth1`.
DSL provider is connected to `eth1`.
I have default internet on `eth0`.
I wish to `docker` container to dial `pppoe` on `eth1` and apps in docker to use that internet with full access to internet without port mapping.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason why you cannot do what you are attempting.   Add the flag

```
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN
```

to the docker run command.  This will give the container sufficient privileges to create and configure interfaces.

Comment: it works with `--net=host` but it is exactly same network. If I change route then it is changed on the host. What I wish to do is to have different routes on host and in container to use different internet providers.

Comment: Is it even possible to have two internet providers dialled at the same time via the same DSL line?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to run with the host's network stack.  You won't have any network isolation between containers, but eth1 will be there as if you were running a regular process.

To do this, use `docker run --net=host [rest of run command]`

It may also be possible to [build your own bridge](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge) and link a veth from the container to the bridge to eth1.  I haven't tried that, nor have I ever tried to control pppoe.

Comment: It is unable to change route. `apt-get install pppoeconf` does not work in docker also. It is other question.